# Securely erase the drive with DBAN using USB to boot

Tags: boot, dell, rufus, secure-erase

I am selling my laptop and I want to make sure to erase all the data.

I am on ubuntu 18.04 in Dell. I have tried to use DBAN with a USB boot. I am using rufus to create my boot, but when I run rufus and I chose DBAN ios, the partition scheme is fixed to MBR and not GPT. I am searching for a way to create an USB bootable with GPT partition scheme.

Comment: DBAN may not be a UEFI-capable ISO.  From what I can tell, in BIOS you should switch the drive to Legacy/MBR mode, then boot to DBAN and wipe the disk.  Then switching back to UEFI will keep the system UEFI-capable.  But I don't think DBAN has a UEFI-bootable ISO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBAN is a MBR-only ISO and as such does NOT have a UEFI bootable mode - it is fairly old even though it still works, and doesn't have a UEFI boot option in it.  You can take the approach of switching your BIOS/system to MBR, run DBAN, then switch to UEFI again.  The  data will still be gone on disk.

---

However, I may have an **alternative to DBAN**, if you're interested: Use an Ubuntu installation / Live USB disk as a base, then use tools in Linux already to erase the disk.

Instead of writing DBAN to a USB, there are tools you can use already in Linux, and can erase data with ease like DBAN does.  Both the options I suggest here start with writing Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 Desktop LiveUSB to the disk instead (20.04 recommended).  Reboot to that disk.

Then, ppen up a terminal in the LiveUSB and run `sudo fdisk -l` and find the hard drive in question.  It should have an `/dev/sdX` type indicator (where X is a letter) or an `nvmeXnY` (where X is a number and Y is a number).

***The `dd` approach***

Then run this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/DEVNAME bs=1024
```

... where `DEVNAME` is the device found in the previous set of commands.

This will run and overwrite your disk with zeros from start to end.  **Note that this will take a long time without any progress indicator.**

If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 in your LiveUSB, then use this, which *does* have a status indicator:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/DEVNAME status=progress
```

***The `dcfldd` approach***

This requires you to first run in the LiveUSB these commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

The program `dcfldd` is a modified version of `dd` in the Universe repository designed for work with forensics specialty so it has a lot of other tools and hash sum verifications to validate wipes and hashes.  This also comes with status meters for progress, and reports as it goes (in Ubuntu 18.04, `dd` did not have this, so if you are using 18.04 in your LiveUSB for this, you may want to use the `dcfldd` option instead if you want a progress indicator)

It uses a larger block size (`bs`) by default, but is also more than capable of wiping your disks, and is an alternative to `dd` because it has status tracking and indications as it goes.

Similar to above, use:

```
sudo dcfldd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/DEVNAME status=on
```

What this does is runs `dcfldd` with the same options, except it defaults to the 32768 bytesize block size for how it processes.  This also has a status indicator which we're forcing 'on' here.

This essentially does the same thing as `dd`, but is faster and has a guarantee of a status indicator.

Comment: I have checked the Boot options, I have only UEFI, the legacy boot mode is not supported.

Comment: by "writing Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 Desktop LiveUSB to the disk instead (20.04 recommended)", you mean I create a bootable ubuntu USB stick?

Comment: Correct, but only the installer, as in the standard ISOs you'd use to install Ubuntu with.  Write that to the USB, and it can boot into UEFI mode.  you can then utilize one of the other tools in my answer to wipe the target drive.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is there any difference with the two ways you have mentioned and the erasing using the shred command?

Comment: @FarahMind the manpage for `shred` says that there are examples of filesystems where `shred` does not work - such as "log-structured or journaled file systems such as those supplied with AIX and Solaris (and JFS, ReiserFFS, Ext3, etc.)".  Ubuntu uses ext4 by default which is one of those journaled file systems.  Therefore "many modern file system designs" do not satisfy the original assumptions behind `shred` which is that the filesystem overwrites in place. `dd` and the `dcfldd` ways write direct to disk AND overwrite the filesystem journal in the process (first 32 bytes) - `shred` doesn't.

Comment: `dd` and `dcfldd` are closer to what DBAN does.